# AsyncListDiffer onAfterSubmitList Listener

Tags: android, android-asynclistdiffer

I'm trying to call `recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView,null,0)` only after `mDiffer.submitlist(list)` is finished "diffing" and animating the list updates/changes.

Is there an AsyncListDiffer feature for `onAfterSubmitList(Callback callback)` that I could use to achieve this?

If not, is there anyway to find out when does `submitList()` finish its task so I could put my `scrollToPosition(0)` in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update July 2020:**

Google added a callback for this! See: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/AsyncListDiffer#submitList(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.lang.Runnable)

**Previous answer, from the bad old days:**

First of all, I can't believe Google didn't provide a callback for this.

I dived into the source code of `AsyncListDiffer`, and I found that it's possible to receive a callback when all RecyclerView updates have been done - but the way to receive this callback is just bizarre.

You need to create a sub-class of `BatchingListUpdateCallback`, and then wrap your `ListUpdateCallback` (or `AdapterListUpdateCallback` as in most cases) inside it.

Then, you should override `dispatchLastEvent`. `AsyncListDiffer` will call this after all but one of the updates have been dispatched. In your `dispatchLastEvent`, you'll want to call the super implementation, so you don't break anything. You'll also want to invoke a custom callback, which is your way in.

In Kotlin that looks like:

```
class OnDiffDoneListUpdateCallback(
    listUpdateCallback: ListUpdateCallback,
    private val onDiffDoneCallback: () -> Unit
) : BatchingListUpdateCallback(listUpdateCallback) {
    override fun dispatchLastEvent() {
        super.dispatchLastEvent()
        onDiffDoneCallback()
    }
}
```

The last step is to then provide your custom `OnDiffDoneListUpdateCallback` to the `AsyncListDiffer`. To do this, you need to initialise the `AsyncListDiffer` for yourself - if you're using `ListAdapter` or something similar, you'll need to refactor so that you are in control of the `AsyncListDiffer`.

In Kotlin, that looks like:

```
private val asyncListDiffer = AsyncListDiffer<ItemType>(
        OnDiffDoneListUpdateCallback(AdapterListUpdateCallback(adapter)) {
            // here's your callback
            doTheStuffAfterDiffIsDone()
        },
        AsyncDifferConfig.Builder<ItemType>(diffCallback).build()
    )
```

Edit:
I forgot about the edge-cases, of course!

Sometimes, `dispatchLastEvent` isn't called, because `AsyncListDiffer` considers the update trivial. Here's the checks it does:

```
    if (newList == mList) {
        ...
        return;
    }

    // fast simple remove all
    if (newList == null) {
        ...
        mUpdateCallback.onRemoved(0, countRemoved);
        return;
    }

    // fast simple first insert
    if (mList == null) {
        ...
        mUpdateCallback.onInserted(0, newList.size());
        return;
    }
```

I recommend doing these checks for yourself, just before you call `asyncListDiffer.submitList(list)`. But of course, it couldn't be that easy! `mList` is private, and `getCurrentList` will return an empty list if `mList` is null, so is useless for this check. Instead you'll have to use reflection to access it:

```
    val listField = AsyncListDiffer::class.java.getDeclaredField("mList")
    listField.isAccessible = true
    val asyncDifferList = listField.get(asyncListDiffer) as List<ItemType>?

    asyncListDiffer.submitList(newList)

    if(asyncDifferList == null) {
        onDiffDone()
    }
    if(newList == null) {
        onDiffDone()
    }
    if(newList == asyncDifferList) {
        onDiffDone()
    }
```

Edit 2: Now, I know what you're saying - surely there's an easier, less hacky way to do this? And the answer is... yes! Simply copy the entire `AsyncListDiffer` class into your project, and just add the callback yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You can get advantage  from [`registerAdapterDataObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#registeradapterdataobserver) methods by listening to them (or what your needs need) i.e:

```
listAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            override fun onChanged() {
                //
            }

            override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {

            }

            override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int, payload: Any?) {

            }

            override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {

            }

            override fun onItemRangeMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int, itemCount: Int) {

            }

            override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {

            }
        })
```

You can clear the register of your `adapterObserver` once needed using [`unregisterAdapterDataObserver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#unregisterAdapterDataObserver(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver)).